# Duplicate Headers via HTTP Request

Tags: c#, .net, http, httpwebrequest

I need to send duplicate headers with an HttpWebRequest. The Headers property combines multiple values if you do something like...

```
req.Headers.Add("name","john");
req.Headers.Add("name","david");
```

What gets sent is...

```
name: john, david
```

What I want is...

```
name: john
name: david
```

I understand that what I want will result in errors for some web servers, but the server that I am interfacing with explicitly requires what I am asking for. Any advice on how to get around this is appreciated. Are there any third party options?

Thanks.

Comment: The property is marked as overridable, you could do your own HttpWebRequest implementation but it might be long and painful. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webrequest.headers.aspx

Comment: What you want is just one of multiple ways to send the header field, so it's valid. What's broken is the server which doesn't support that notation.

Comment: No, the server does support that notation, and it explicitly requires it. What doesn't support it, as far as I can find, is .NET.

Comment: I think what .NET is doing here is correct according to [RFC 7230](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7230#section-3.2.2):

"A sender MUST NOT generate multiple header fields with the same field
name in a message unless either the entire field value for that
header field is defined as a comma-separated list [i.e., #(values)]
or the header field is a well-known exception"

Comment: It would be nice to do this for testing purposes. Even if it isn't a correct request, it would be useful to have a way to send duplicate headers to test a server's response.